# How does the rewrite works in web.config system.webserver

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an asp.net mvc 4 application and i have this rule in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Remove Virtual Directory">
      <match url=".*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I can't understand why and how this works. I use it because godaddy adds a virtual path in the url with the name of the folder the application is in.
i.e. `example.com/foldername/index` becomes `example.com/index`

So how does it finds the virual path by ".*" and removes it. And what {R:0} is?
Thank you.

Comment: Is this rule in a `web.config` which is not in the root of the server?

Comment: @cheesemacfly It is not in the root of the server. it is in a folder. Where the web app is in there. the web config is in the root of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well It seems that I the match url this regex matches every url and it doesn't allow to redirect a url that includes the virtual path. Since the routing of mvc finds the resource.

As for {R:0}. The request url is the first argument hence the 0, and the regex is a secont argument not uses. This would be the {R:1}.